# Crystal Reports into HTML and sending in my mail as body

Tags: .net, email, outlook, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report in VB.NET. I want to send report as body in mail using microsoft outlook.

My code is as below, it convert Crystal Report in to html in body section of outlook but it is showing with html tags.

```
Private Sub FrmViewReport_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try

        Dim mailbodybutton As New ToolStripButton
        mailbodybutton.Image = ts.Items(10).Image
        ts.Items.Remove(ts.Items(10))
        ts.Items.Insert(10, mailbodybutton)
        AddHandler ts.Items(10).Click, AddressOf CaptureMailBodyEvent

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub CaptureMailBodyEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyClass.Click
    Try
        Dim oStream As System.IO.MemoryStream

        oStream = objReport.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.HTML40)
        oStream.Position = 0
        Dim sr = New System.IO.StreamReader(oStream)
        Dim html = sr.ReadToEnd()

        Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
        Dim appNameSpace As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace
        Dim memo As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem

        app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application

        appNameSpace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        appNameSpace.Logon(Nothing, Nothing, False, False)

        memo = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)

        memo.Subject = NVlTrim(m_ReportTitle, "Report")
        memo.Body = html
        memo.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML

        memo.Display()


    Catch ex As Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub
```

It should show as showing in Crystal Report instead of HTML Tags

Answer (score 0):

You should Try

```
memo.HTMLBody = html
```